# Need help understanding some abstract class code

Tags: c#

I am a newb when it comes to programming and truth be told i cnnot wrap my head around C# (it's part of my college courses to learn it). So anyway my prof gave us some code to solve as our second last homework activity and with barely to no documentation or context of what to do. I don't understand this code in the slightest (the abstract class part of it) and i was wondering if someone can explain to me what is going in this code so i can at least understand what i am supposed to do. 
Code below:

```
public class Point
    {
        public double x;
        public double y;
    }
//=============================================================================
    public abstract class Shape
    {
        public Point Centre { get; set; } = new Point();

        public Shape(double x, double y)
        {
            //set Center point to parameter values


        }

        public void Move(double dx, double dy)
        {
            //increment center to dx and dy amount.

        }

        public abstract double GetArea();
        public abstract double GetPerimeter();

        public bool IsSmallerThan(Shape other)
        {
            // return true if this objects's area is smaller that parameter objects's area.
            // return false otherwise.

        }
    }
```

I dont need the solution I just wanna know what the comments mean and thought that the code can be an added context needed. Thank you guys in advance (I hope im posting this the right way)

Comment: Looks like you should add code that will do smth explained in comments

Comment: All you have to do is to google for these things and read up. Tons of info out there. This site is to solve programming problems, not teach basics

Comment: well yes but you see I don't understand how to set point to parameter values, i did some googling but it yielded no results and my prof is not answering. English is not my first language, and 90% of the time I have a dictionary along with a translator to help me understand the material.

Comment: Just quit your college and find something you can do. //set Center point to parameter values - `Centre = new Point(x, y);`

Comment: Thank you for the help but unfortunatly i need to be in college in order to finish the IT program, plus I understand C++, SQL Server and Java/Javascript a lot better then C#. I do not know why I have such a hard time with it.

Comment: Actually, c# should be nice for you. And college should not be needed soon. We need to learn how to grow own veggies and take care of cows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abstract methods are different for different shape types.

For a square (which would be a class extending Shape), the area is different than a triangle. But all the square have the area calculated similarly.

The other methods (which have comments inside of them) are based on those abstract methods and don't depend on the shape itself. For example, moving a shape is simply moving its center.